# Extract All Instances of String into Concatenated Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, text-parsing

Using SQL Server 2014, I'm wanting to search within a field and return all instances of a string that is found, plus the following word. For example, the text in the column may be:

"exec sproc1 and then some more text here and then maybe execute sproc2 exec storedproc3 and maybe exec sproc1"

I'd like to elegantly return "sproc1, sproc2, storedproc3, sproc1", as each was the word following either exec or execute (as delimited by spaces). As you can see in the example, the leading word may vary, as may the length of the sproc name. I've been able to return the first usage of exec/execute; my issue is that sometimes there are multiple (see below).

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE
        WHEN [sJSTP].[subsystem]='TSQL' AND CHARINDEX('EXECUTE',[sJSTP].[command],1)>0
            THEN SUBSTRING([sJSTP].[command],CHARINDEX('EXECUTE',[sJSTP].[command],1)+8,
                IIF(
                CHARINDEX(' ',[sJSTP].[command],CHARINDEX('EXECUTE',[sJSTP].[command],1)+8)>0,
                CHARINDEX(' ',[sJSTP].[command],CHARINDEX('EXECUTE',[sJSTP].[command],1)+8)-CHARINDEX('EXECUTE',[sJSTP].[command],1)-8,
                LEN([sJSTP].[command])))
        WHEN [sJSTP].[subsystem]='TSQL' AND CHARINDEX('EXEC',[sJSTP].[command],1)>0 AND CHARINDEX('DCEXEC',[sJSTP].[command],1)<=0
            THEN SUBSTRING([sJSTP].[command],CHARINDEX('EXEC',[sJSTP].[command],1)+5,
                IIF(
                CHARINDEX(' ',[sJSTP].[command],CHARINDEX('EXEC',[sJSTP].[command],1)+5)>0,
                CHARINDEX(' ',[sJSTP].[command],CHARINDEX('EXEC',[sJSTP].[command],1)+5)-CHARINDEX('EXEC',[sJSTP].[command],1)-5,
                LEN([sJSTP].[command])))
    END,'[',''),']','') AS sprocname
```

The ultimate use of this is parsing job commands from the msdb..sysjobsteps table to see what stored procedures are being used.

**Edit:** Add sample data

**Sample 1:**
exec quarterly_run 1, 'BW'
exec quarterly_run_2 1, 'QR '
exec quarterly_run 2, 'VAS'
exec quarterly_run 1, 'WR'
exec quarterly_run 3, 'RW'
exec quarterly_run_2 1, 'ASF'
exec quarterly_run_3 1, 'ALL'

**Sample 2:**
declare @rundate datetime, @rptqtr datetime, @qtr int

set @rundate = getdate()
set @rptqtr = '06/30/2016'

set @qtr = (select datediff(quarter,@rptqtr,@rundate))

exec quarterly_extract @qtr

**Sample 3:**
exec Daily_Sync_Process
exec Daily_Process

Comment: You need an actual string splitter, not just charindex. If you can share some sample data as one your struggling with I can help. Or if you want to tackle it yourself here are some great splitters. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: what about jobs that don't explicitly use exec or execute?

Comment: Sample data has been added; thank you for any help you can provide! As far as jobs not using exec or execute - in our environment that does not happen, so it would not apply here, but great catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another inline option, and not limited to 8K

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert into @YourTable values
 (1,'exec quarterly_run 1, ''BW'' exec quarterly_run_2 1, ''QR '' exec quarterly_run 2, ''VAS'' exec quarterly_run 1, ''WR'' exec quarterly_run 3, ''RW'' exec quarterly_run_2 1, ''ASF'' exec quarterly_run_3 1, ''ALL''')
,(2,'declare @rundate datetime, @rptqtr datetime, @qtr int

set @rundate = getdate() set @rptqtr = ''06/30/2016''

set @qtr = (select datediff(quarter,@rptqtr,@rundate))

exec quarterly_extract @qtr
')
,(3,'exec Daily_Sync_Process exec Daily_Process')

;with cte as (
Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values (replace(replace(SomeCol,char(13),' '),char(10),' '))) B(CleanString)
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq,RetVal = case when Lag(RetVal,1) over (Order by RetSeq) in ('Exec','Execute') then RetVal else null end
                From (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(CleanString,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                     ) C1
             ) C
)
Select A.ID
      ,NewString = Stuff((Select ', ' +RetVal From cte Where ID=A.ID Order By RetSeq For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') 
 From cte A
 Group By A.ID
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewString
1   quarterly_run, quarterly_run_2, quarterly_run, quarterly_run, quarterly_run, quarterly_run_2, quarterly_run_3
2   quarterly_extract
3   Daily_Sync_Process, Daily_Process
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to get what is immediately following `exec` then I'd split on the space, and then use a self join.  Here is code using the function below, which is [Jeff Moden's splitter.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
with cte as(
select
    job_id
    ,step_name
    ,step_id
    ,s.ItemNumber
    ,s.Item
from msdb..sysjobsteps
--split on the space
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(command,' ') s)

select 
    c.job_id
    ,c.step_id
    ,c.step_name
    ,c.Item
    ,c2.Item
from cte c
--self join to get exec myproc in the same row
full join
    cte c2 on 
    c2.ItemNumber = c.ItemNumber + 1 
    and c.job_id = c2.job_id
    and c.step_id = c2.step_id
--we only care where the base table has exec or execute (not executed, etc)
where c.Item = 'exec' or c.Item = 'execute'
order by 
    c.job_id, c.step_id, c.ItemNumber
```

It's important to realize this would fail when, for example, the command was `exec  someproc` which has two spaces. You can fix that with a `replace()` but you'd have to nest this replace multiple times to account for as many spaces as you want. You'd handle that on the `command` column in the splitter function

```
--here we replace two spaces with 1 for the entire command
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(replace(command,'  ',' '),' ') s)
```

**SPLITER FUNCTION**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000... enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l


GO
```

Comment: The biggest problem though is that it will not take varchar(max) which the command column in that table is. Would likely work most of the time as it would implicitly convert it but if the original is longer it won't work.

Comment: Bad habits of linking tally table lol. Good catch @SeanLange . Also good catch on the `varchar(max)`.  Maybe a CLR?

Comment: This should work unless the text is stupidly long. And if they are using procedures I would sure as hell hope they don't have so many procedures calls in a single step that it gets even close to 8,000 characters. :)